# So how do I work around not having a shared global scope in PHP threads

Tags: php, multithreading, global

OK, so I can't use global in php threads anymore as of pthreads3. Is there some other way to share data across threads? (Without having tried it...) Can I use a shared memory object as long as each thread has a separate handle?

I'm using threads because I have a set of identical tasks that can be run in parallel using the same script. Let's say I'm using SNMP to watch 100 printers to see if their toner is low. I could have 100 separate PHP processes each its own memory foot print, local configuration variable etc. that are all the same except for one little IP address. OR I could have just one php process running 100 threads that share the foot print of a single php process and the majority of the configuration variable except for that one string. I am doing that now on PHP5/pthreads2, but I really want to move up to PHP7 just to stay current and because the security task force says php5 is 2 revision old you must update. (not that 5 is actually 2 major revisions out of date, but you know...) Anyway I can't use my existing code because I can't share the global space between my threads anymore.

What's the right way to do this?

Comment: file storage, db storage, mem cache ...